# Why are the timestamps incorrect when debugging App Engine Python code

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Under my debugger:

```
logging.info("TZ = %s -- It is now: %s", os.environ['TZ'], time.ctime())
TZ = UTC -- It is now: Mon Oct 17 12:10:44 2011
```

Under App Engine Launcher:

```
logging.info("TZ = %s -- It is now: %s", os.environ['TZ'], time.ctime())
TZ = UTC -- It is now: Mon Oct 17 17:09:24 2011
```

So what do I have setup wrong?  This affects not just time.ctime(), but all the data dropped into the debug database.  I'd like the debugger to run in the same "timeframe" as the app engine launcher because of timestamps in the database, and the debugger is slower than the launcher, so I don't want to use it all the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that the C runtime functions on Windows with Python 2.5 seem to cache the value of the TZ environment variable the first time either time or ctime is called.  The following will display the time in local time and not in UTC:

```
import time, os
time.time()
os.environ['TZ'] = 'UTC'
print time.ctime()
```

Wing's debugger calls time() before running any AppEngine code so the initial value of TZ was captured.  The workaround is to set TZ=UTC in the environment variables via the project properties dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand your problem better (you want your debugger to run on UTC, like GAE's default), this gets exciting and tricky.  [logging.Formatter.formatTime](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter.formatTime) defaults to formatting dates according to [time.localtime()](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.localtime).  To change this, set the `converter` attribute to [time.gmtime()](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.gmtime).  This is barely documented, but I found a blog about [Logging with UTC Timestamps from Python](http://od-eon.com/blogs/stefan/logging-utc-timestamps-python/) that may be what you're looking for.

Tell me if this is not helpful; it may be that I still misunderstand what you're asking.

---

**Old Answer:** [ctime](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.ctime) will always convert to local time.  The local time on the server is different from the local time for your home computer's debugger.  You can set os `os.environ` time zone variable to whatever you want; `time.ctime()` won't care.

Try [formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime) [time.gmtime()](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.gmtime) and you'll be using Greenwich Mean Time for both.

```
gmt = time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime())
logging.info("It is now: %s", gmt)
-- It is now: Mon 17 Oct 2011 19:11:10
```

Comment: Ok, but I'm really trying to get the datastore to use that time frame.  I just printed it out to show the problem.  I'm using things like `db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)` and the value of that is changing based on Launcher or Debugger.

Comment: Hmm, the [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#DateTimeProperty) say "Date-time values are stored as and returned using the UTC time zone," so I see no reason for the discrepancy... maybe the debugger is bugged?  I'll search more.

Comment: Are you debugging with `pdb`?

Comment: At this point I punted to the Wing folks and had this solved in a matter of hours.  I wasn't sure how the IDE was doing the debug, but they have an option to set the environment and all that was needed was to add to the current environment the string TZ=UTC.  I couldn't fix it with  `os.environ['TZ'] = 'UTC'` but the extra environment option did the trick.